# Is there a way to set a keyboard shortcut to open containing folder of a selected file in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I click on a C++ project in Visual Studio, I get this menu:

[image]

And so I can quickly press `Alt+F,F`(Command `ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Project.OpenFolderinFileExplorer`) to open the folder of the project.

I also found that I can open containing folder if I open the file in the Text Editor in Visual Studio:
[image]

I bound it to `Alt+F,F` as well. I set it to only be active in Text Editor, it's the `File.OpenContainingFolder` command.

But when I click on files inside the project in the Solution Explorer, there is no context menu:
[image]

I tried to make the `File.OpenContainingFolder` command global, but it still doesn't work in the Solution Explorer when I just click on a file once. If I double click it and open it in the text editor, it works.

And I can't find a command in the `Keyboard` section in options of Visual Studio to open containing folder of a file selected in the Solution Explorer.

Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external tool menu item, and then bind a shortcut to that item.

1. Go to `Tools > External Tools`.
2. Click `Add`.
3. In Title edit box type `Show in Explorer`.
4. In Command edit box type `explorer.exe`.
5. In Arguments edit box type `/select, $(ItemPath)`. There is a space between a comma and a dollar sign.
6. Click `OK`.
7. Make note at the position of the new command in the list. It could be first, it could be fifth, or something else. Let's assume it's the fifth one.
8. Assign a shortcut to the command `Tools.ExternalCommand5`. Restrict the shortcut to Solution Explorer.

That's it.